# Loading value from json upon start up application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I want to load the values from json file upon the Spring Boot Application is started.

My code for the Configuration File is like the below:

```
@Configuration
@Getter
public class FedexAPIConfig {

    private final static String JSON_FILE = "/static/config/fedex-api-credentials.json";
    private final boolean IS_PRODUCTION = false;
    private FedexAPICred apiCredentials;

    public FedexAPIConfig() {
        try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(JSON_FILE);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            // this.apiCredentials = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));
            
            if (IS_PRODUCTION) {
                json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader)).getJSONObject("production");
            } else {
                json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader)).getJSONObject("test");
            }
            System.out.println(json.toString());
            this.apiCredentials = FedexAPICred.builder()
                    .url(json.optString("url"))
                    .apiKey(json.optString("api_key"))
                    .secretKey(json.optString("secret_key"))
                    .build();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and with this, when the application is in progress of startup, values are successfully printed on the console.[Startup console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzqzN.png)

When I tried to call this value from other ordinary class, like the below:, it brings nothing but just throws NullPointerException... What are my faults and what shall I do?

```
public class FedexOAuthTokenManager extends OAuthToken {
    private static final String VALIDATE_TOKEN_URL = "/oauth/token";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_CLIENT = "client_credentials";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_CSP = "csp_credentials";

    @Autowired
    private FedexAPIConfig fedexApiConfig;

    @Autowired
    private Token token;

    @Override
    public void validateToken() {
        // This is the part where "fedexApiConfig" is null.
        FedexAPICred fedexApiCred = fedexApiConfig.getApiCredentials();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE_CLIENT)
                    .add("client_id", fedexApiCred.getApiKey())
                    .add("client_secret", fedexApiCred.getSecretKey())
                    .build();

            response = new HttpClient().post(fedexApiCred.getUrl() + VALIDATE_TOKEN_URL, body);
            
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

                token.setAccessToken(json.optString("access_token"));
                token.setTokenType(json.optString("token_type"));
                token.setExpiredIn(json.optInt("expires_in"));
                token.setExpiredDateTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(json.optInt("expires_in")));
                token.setScope(json.optString("scope"));

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

fedexApiConfg is null even though I autowired it in prior to call.
And this FedexOAuthTokenManager is called from other @Component class by new FedexOAuthTokenManager()

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like below?

**Step 1: Create one Configuration class like below**

```
public class DemoConfig implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        
        //Load the values from the JSON file and populate the application 
        //properties dynamically 
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.datasource.url", "<my value>");
        //Add more properties
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("myProps", props));

    }
```

To listen to a context event, a bean should implement the ApplicationListener interface which has just one method onApplicationEvent().The ApplicationPreparedEvent is invoked very early in the lifecycle of the application

**Step 2: Customize in src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories**

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=com.example.demo.DemoConfig
```

**Step 3: @Value in spring boot is commonly used to inject the configuration values into the spring boot application. Access the properties as per your wish.**

```
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String valueFromJSon;
```

Try this sample first in your local machine and then modify your changes accordingly.

Refer - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Refer - https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2021/02/aws-secret-manager-service-as.html